# Generate figures with 3D bars overlay and 2D image

Tags: 3d

Right now I have a Voronoi tesselation plot generated from R, and each tesselated polygon has an associated value (denoted as **N**). What I want to achieve is to plot a 3D barplot using those **N**s.

In principle it should look like to this:

[image]

Where in my case, each state should be a polygon and each 3D bar is generated using those **N**. I am stuck because I am not sure which software should I use to do this, any thoughts?